# Do Different CRM Orgs Running On The Same Box Share The Same App Domain?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm doing some in memory Caching for some Plugins in Microsoft CRM.  I'm attempting to figure out if I need to be concerned about different orgs populating the same cache:

```cs
// In Some Plugin
var settings = Singleton.GetCache["MyOrgSpecificSetting"];
// Use Org specific cached Setting:
```

or do I need to do something like this to be sure I don't cross contaminate settings:

```cs
// In Some Plugin
var settings = Singleton.GetCache[GetOrgId() + "MyOrgSpecificSetting"];
// Use Org specific cached Setting:
```

I'm guessing this would also need to be factored in for Custom Activities in the AsyncWorkflowService as well?

Answer (score 2):

Great question. As far as I understand, you would run into the issue you describe if you set static data if your assemblies were not registered in Sandbox Mode, so you would have to create some way to uniquely qualify the reference (as your second example does).

**However**, this goes against Microsoft's best practices in Plugin/Workflow Activity development. Every plugin should not rely on state outside of the state that is passed into the plugin. Here is what it says on MSDN found [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328263.aspx):

> The plug-in's Execute method should be written to be stateless because
>   the constructor is not called for every invocation of the plug-in.
>   Also, multiple system threads could execute the plug-in at the same
>   time. All per invocation state information is stored in the context,
>   so you should not use global variables or attempt to store any data in
>   member variables for use during the next plug-in invocation unless
>   that data was obtained from the configuration parameter provided to
>   the constructor.

So the ideal way to managage caching would be to use either one or more CRM records (likely custom) or use a different service to cache this data.

Comment: I'm attempting to create a cached version of a web resource that has been deserialized...  So I know what I'm doing when I'm going against Microsoft's best practices.  So if its registered in sandbox mode, it's basically segregated in its own app domain?

Comment: Basically, yes. The Sandbox mode makes it so your code runs isolated from other deployments, which enables an environment like CRM online to allow multiple tenants to run independently of one another.

The thing I'm not sure about is how long the cache will last. If you want to cache data, I would recommend something like Redis or AppFabric (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppFabric_Caching)

Comment: We have a third party that hosts our CRM.  I'm not sure if we have access to be able to install app fabric.  Since we have multiple severs I'm using a "poor man's" cache that expires every hour.  This way we know every server will refresh its cached values every hour.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous plugins of all organizations within CRM front-end run in the same AppDomain. So your second approach will work.  Unfortunately async services are running in separate process from where it would not be possible to access your in-proc cache.

Comment: So yes, I'll need to be concerned which Org I'm in.  I'll have a duplicate cache on the Async servers to be worried about updating if the value ever changes?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's technically impossible for Microsoft *NOT* to implement each CRM **organization** in at least its own AppDomain, let alone an AppDomain per loaded assembly. I'm trying to imagine how multiple versions of a plugin-assembly are deployed to multiple organizations and loaded and executed in the same AppDomain and I can't think of a realistic way. But that may be my lack of imagination.

I think your problem lies more in the concurrency (multi-threading) than in sharing of the same plugin across organizations. @BlueSam quotes Microsoft where they seem to be saying that multiple instances of the same plugin can live in one AppDomain. Make sure multiple threads can concurrently read/write to your in-mem cache and you'll be fine. And if you really really want to be sure, prepend the cache key with the OrgId, like in your second example.

I figure you'll be able to implement a concurrent cache, so I won't go into detail there.